# Solr sort by field value

Tags: sorting, solr

i try to sort response from "apache solr" by field value.
This is my sort function:

```
sort=if(eq(custom_s_doctor_location_key, "advanced imaging center - lake ridge-landing"),1,0) desc
```

But i get error:

```
  "error":{
"metadata":[
  "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
  "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
"msg":"Can't determine a Sort Order (asc or desc) in sort spec 'if(eq(custom_s_doctor_location_key, \"advanced imaging center - lake ridge-landing\"),1,0) desc', pos=35",
"code":400}})
```

Answer (score 0):

custom_s_doctor_location_key is a numeric field? If it is not, you would need to use some other function like [strdist](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/function-queries.html) to compare as string. I would be cumbersome but should work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the case here, but I had exactly the same error when trying to sort by not existing field.

Make sure `custom_s_doctor_location_key` described in your `schema.xml` (or something like `*_key`)

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the correct version of Solr? Seems like "eq" was introduced in solr 6.2 http://yonik.com/solr-6-2/